# PIR motion sensor HW-416-B does not behave properly. No motion but input is triggered regardless

Tags: rpi.gpio, sensor, motion

So, this motion sensor works when it is taped to my desktop computer...but when I move it to the wall, specifically a higher spot on the wall, it just keeps giving back an input signal. So here is a script I am using:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
PIR_PIN = 2
GPIO.setup(PIR_PIN, GPIO.IN)
i = 0
try:
        print("PIR Module Test (CTRL+C to exit)")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Ready")
        while True:
                if GPIO.input(PIR_PIN):
                        i = i + 1
                        time.sleep(1)
                        print(i)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Quit")
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

Simple and straight forward.

This is the output

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python motion.py
PIR Module Test (CTRL+C to exit)
Ready
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

and so on. So when I move the location of the sensor in a higher spot in the room, the sensor just keeps going off. I'm trying to understand why.

Comment: try to adjust the sensitivity with potentiometer present on the sensor..

Answer (score 0):

The code itself is pretty fine. I have just checked, and it looks your issue is very similar the one that described [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/220641/pir-sensor-always-gives-high) as the modules are pretty similar. Hence, try to increase your delay before to while loop to 1 min to see if it helps.

For these kind of questions please include a diagram that shows how you connected your sensor module, and a datasheet of the module so we can check specs.

Comment: I followed what the poster did and it didn't help me. It temporarily helps, but not for long.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is having problems with this, it was because the sensor was placed too close to the RPi. I had to extend the wiring and move it a good 5 feet away. This solved the problem, mostly, although it still exhibited odd behavior.